# Swift | Use multiple conditions with #available

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering if you can use multiple conditions with an `#available` if statement.
Where if the version is of iOS the user is on, meets the requirements AND another condition is fulfilled.

Something like:

```swift
if #available(iOS 16, *)
   && fooBar == false 
{
    // conditions met
}
```

Because it returns: `error: unexpected code '&& fooBar == false' in 'if' statement` when I try it.

It has to also be within the if statement, it cannot be check for ios version, then do something as the code would need significant rewrite for it to work otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separating the two conditions with a comma will work:

```swift
if #available(iOS 16, *), fooBar == false {
    // conditions met
}
```

Comment: Too bad this doesn't work in Objective-C.